# How to save content of applet in jsp to database using servlet programming

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, applet

I am developing a jsp which contains a applet which captures the image from webcam and shows in same applet.What my need is to save captured image in database through jsp form submit with some other request parametera.Until now i did it by saving the captured image in user directory of local system and then i am reading it form local system directory and then i am using JDBC PreparedStatement.

Now What my need is to to save the Captured Image in Applet with out saving it to local directory.Is it possible to read applet content through the streams?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Until now i did it by saving the captured image in user directory of local system` - do you mean a local system on the server or on the client side?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading your question correctly, you're looking to save images in a database instead of the user's local file system.  This is certainly possible - though I'd usually recommend storing only metadata about the images in a database, and keeping the images themselves on a file system.  In your case, this would probably mean the file system of a server, and not the local desktop running the applet.

If you do want to save the images *in* the database, JDBC would allow for this.  You'll need a database column of a BLOB (binary large object) type, and use the `getBlob`/`setBlob` JDBC methods.

Regardless of whether you decide to store the images in a database or the file system on the server, keep in mind that applet security will require your applet to only communicate with the host that the applet is being served from - so you need to host the database or proxy the database connection through the same server that the applet is being served from.

Comment: Thanks for reply.May be i am i am wrong with my explanation.Here how it goes in my jsp. My jsp contains an applet which responsible for capturing images through capture button in jsp.When capture button is pressed my applet was in desgined in such way that it paints the capture image in applet and saves the captured image in user directory of local system of use who is using my jsp.Now when i sumbit my jsp i am reading from local user directory( of cource not good approach) and writng it into web server temp files.Then iam uploading it into database which very bad approach.

Comment: What other questions do you have?

Comment: Now my question is instead of doing all this stuff , when jsp form is sumbitted with captured image ,is there is any way to read contents of applet which is nothing but a capture image(not exactly image look like image) through any kind of  input streams in servlets.

Comment: Not directly from the JSP / HTML, no.  This pretty much would need to be done from within the applet.

Comment: Thank u.One more question actually applets not require any webservers,but it can be placed in jsp.Now My Jsp is runnig under a specific webserver. Is there is any way the applet can get the information of webserver  when it was used by a jsp or html

Comment: Please open a separate question for this, just to keep this on-topic?